# List of linux paths which are 'virtual' files

Tags: linux, rsync

I don't know the correct terminology, and that's probably the reason I can't find a related question here on Superuser.

I have a backup script that syncs my linux server to a remote location. My system isn't very large so it makes sense to backup everything. However, some paths make no sense to backup like /proc/*.

So I exclude it from the process:

```
 rsync -avzh -e "ssh -p 1234" --exclude="/proc" --exclude="/tmp" /
```

But I guess there are more paths like that in linux. Is there a list somewhere with all linux paths with "virtual" files?

Comment: Related questions that might help: http://serverfault.com/questions/74696/linux-what-directories-should-i-exclude-when-backing-up-a-server, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104743/entries-i-can-safely-exclude-doing-backups, http://askubuntu.com/questions/28477/what-is-safe-to-exclude-for-a-full-system-backup

Comment: off the top of my head, the directories to exclude are `/proc`, `/dev`, and you most likely also want to exclude `/tmp` and `/boot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may vary from system to system, depending on distribution, installed software, and configuration.

Enter `mount` or `cat /etc/mtab` in a terminal window. Lines that do *not* start with `/dev/*` refer to virtual filesystems of sorts. This one-liner filters out all lines that start with the aforementioned pattern: `mount | grep -Ev '^/dev/'`.

Sample output:

```
$ mount | grep -Ev '^/dev/'                                                                                                                                         
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)                                                                                                                           
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)                                                                                                                            
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=215485,mode=755)                                                                                                       
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)                                                                                               
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=310348k,mode=755)                                                                                                           
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)                                                                                                           
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1245520k)                                                                                                         
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
```

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` has an option `-x` (a.k.a. `--one-file-system`) which will do a lot of what you want:

```
rsync -ax / <somewhere>
```

That will backup everything that exists in the root filesystem, but skip everything mounted separately, including `/proc`, `/dev`, `/run`, etc. It'll also skip any mounted CDs, SD cards, network drives, etc.

If your distro uses tmpfs for `/tmp` then it'll skip that also, but otherwise you'll still have to do that manually. Likewise, if your distro doesn't use udev then you'll need to skip `/dev` manually also.

Conversely, if your `/home` lives on a separate partition then you'll need to back that up separately, because `-x` would skip that also.